# AWS Route53 - get uptime percentage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-route53

I need to find a way to report on website uptime (as a percentage) based on AWS Route53 monitoring. This reporting is generally done quarterly.

My initial thought was to have CloudWatch send ALARM and OK states via SNS to SQS, and then process this queue into a database for later reporting. As far as I can tell, however, CloudWatch will only send emails even though an SQS queue is subscribed to the topic.

Any suggestions of how I might achieve this?

Comment: You can start with building a `healthcheck` on that website, it generated cloudwatch data for latest 2 weeks.

Comment: Thank you @BMW. Yes, I have set up a health check, however it only stores the data for 2 weeks as you mention, and it also only shows data in a graphical form so can't get a percentage value. I'm hoping to log the alerts sent from the health check somewhere so I can query them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Route 53 can be configured to send healthcheck data to Amazon SQS.

It worked for me -- here's the steps I took:

1. Create an **Amazon SNS notification topic** in `us-east-1` (where Route 53 performs its health checks)
2. Create an **Amazon SQS queue** in `us-east-1` (same region as the notification topic)
3. **Subscribe** the Amazon SQS queue to the Amazon SNS topic (via the Queue Actions menu option)
4. Create an **Amazon Route 53 Health Check**. Set **Create Alarm** to Yes. Configure it to **Send notification to  Existing SNS topic** and choose the topic created above.

An **Amazon CloudWatch alarm** will be automatically created by Amazon Route 53.

This will result in health notifications arriving in the SQS queue. However, it will only send an ALARM notification -- there is **no notification when it becomes healthy again**. To receive a "now healthy" notification, edit the CloudWatch alarm and **add a new Notification** that triggers when "State is OK".

Here is an example of a failure notification retrieved from the SQS queue:

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "4768e8e4-0026-51c7-aa6e-a696bf02f808",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:r53-east",
  "Subject" : "ALARM: \"awsroute53--4c2f-9816-a42c50ec8671-High-HealthCheckStatus\" in US - N. Virginia",
  "Message" : "{\"AlarmName\":\"awsroute53-4c2f-9816-a42c50ec8671-High-HealthCheckStatus\",\"AlarmDescription\":null,\"AWSAccountId\":\"743112987576\",\"NewStateValue\":\"ALARM\",\"NewStateReason\":\"Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (0.0) was less than the threshold (1.0).\",\"StateChangeTime\":\"2015-09-16T00:50:44.591+0000\",\"Region\":\"US - N. Virginia\",\"OldStateValue\":\"OK\",\"Trigger\":{\"MetricName\":\"HealthCheckStatus\",\"Namespace\":\"AWS/Route53\",\"Statistic\":\"MINIMUM\",\"Unit\":null,\"Dimensions\":[{\"name\":\"HealthCheckId\",\"value\":\"4c2f-9816-a42c50ec8671\"}],\"Period\":60,\"EvaluationPeriods\":1,\"ComparisonOperator\":\"LessThanThreshold\",\"Threshold\":1.0}}",
  "Timestamp" : "2015-09-16T00:50:44.656Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "KvCHsBh95q...cw8A==",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-90147a5624348ee.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:r53-east:4b5d-8318-57bd58f0b3a4"
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. I have already tried the steps you suggest however the SQS message never arrives. I'll run back through from the start to make sure I'm not missing something...

Comment: Trace it through... Confirm that the Route 53 health checkers see a state change. Then check that the CloudWatch alarm triggers. Then check that the queue is subscripted to the SNS notification. Finally, toggle the state of the health check (make it healthy, then make it unhealthy) to trigger a new message. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks John - this is working now. I think the difference may have been in step 3. I had subscribed the SQS queue via the SNS interface and this wasn't working. Coming at it from the SQS side seems to have made a difference. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to offload Route53 health check statistics to [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/aws/route53-health-checks/) and enable scheduled reports as discussed in the [uptime reports](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/aws/route53-health-checks/uptime-report.html) article.

Implementation notes:

- Need to create a [read-only account](https://axibase.com/docs/axibase-collector/jobs/aws-iam.html) to query CloudWatch statistics and Route53 Health Check metadata.
- Offload task has a latency of 5-15 minutes (configurable).
- Offload task ensures no data gaps in copied CW statistics, i.e. when collection temporarily stops for whatever reason.

Available reports:

- Base report: average uptime over the period (day, week, month, quarter).
- Enhanced uptime report with additional check configuration details.
- Filter results by protocol or custom tag.
- Aggregate uptime by custom tag such as GEO, environment.
- Filter results by hours of the day or working days.
- Aggregate uptime by day of week.
- Downtime incident count.
- Longest downtime incidents.

The reports can be generated interactively, via a web-based console, delivered via email, or displayed on portals.

[image]

Disclaimer: I work for Axibase.